# How can I separate a column into their own sheet using maps?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to use this map provided by a previous question I had.

In this case, it takes the sales rep's name, creates a sheet with their name and then moves all orders that belong to them to their sheet.  This is what the code looks like.

```
function sortByRep(sheet){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("All Orders");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:H" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues();
  var sheets = [...new Set(values.map(r => r[6]))].reduce((o, e) => (o[e] = ss.getSheetByName(e) || ss.insertSheet(e), o), {});
  [...values.reduce((m, r) => m.set(r[6], m.has(r[6]) ? [m.get(r[6]), r] : r), new Map())]
    .forEach(([k, v]) => {
      var s = sheets[k];
      if (s) s.getRange(s.getLastRow() + 1, 1, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
    });
```

But I get this error:

Exception: The parameters (number,number,number,null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange.

I think it has to be because there are spaces in the names?  But I'm not sure.[image]

I have added this picture as an example.  I want my script to make a new sheet with the sales rep name and move all of their orders to that sheet.

Comment: I'm not a fan of complex functions I can't understand (cause I'm not an advanced expert xD), but maybe separating everything in variables could give you an insight:

Comment: ``` 
function sortByRep(sheet){
  // your code
  var valuesMap = values.map(r => r[6])
  var sheets = [...new Set(valuesMap)]
  var sheetsReduced = sheets.reduce((o, e) => (o[e] = ss.getSheetByName(e) || ss.insertSheet(e), o), {});
  var valuesReduced = [...values.reduce((m, r) => m.set(r[6], m.has(r[6]) ? [m.get(r[6]), r] : r), new Map())]
  
  valuesReduced.forEach(([k, v]) => {
      var s = sheetsReduced[k];
      if (s) s.getRange(s.getLastRow() + 1, 1, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
    });
}
```

Comment: You can also check this trend about the same problem https://support.google.com/docs/thread/112139713/the-parameters-number-don-t-match-the-method-signature-for-spreadsheetapp-range-setvalues?hl=en

Comment: In order to correctly understand your issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet as an image?

Comment: Tanaike, I am so glad you chimed in.  The snippet above was written by you!  I am attaching a picture.

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, I deeply apologize that my script was not useful for your situation. From your additional information, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize, again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
[...values.reduce((m, r) => m.set(r[6], m.has(r[6]) ? [m.get(r[6]), r] : r), new Map())]
  .forEach(([k, v]) => {
    var s = sheets[k];
    if (s) s.getRange(s.getLastRow() + 1, 1, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
  });
```

#### To:

```
[...values.reduce((m, r) => m.set(r[6], m.has(r[6]) ? [...m.get(r[6]), r] : [r]), new Map())]
  .forEach(([k, v]) => {
    var s = sheets[k];
    if (s) s.getRange(s.getLastRow() + 1, 1, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
  });
```

- In this modification, both one row and multiple rows can be used.

Comment: Tanaike, you are a very smart person.  I am jealous of your ability to think these through and I appreciate the time you take to help people.

This works great when the sales rep has one order but when they have multiple orders, I get this: [Ljava.lang.Object;@1b854588

Comment: @Patrick Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience, again. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize, again.